# Can't USe Kendo UI Widget in Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I have Add Kendo.Mvc.dll (version :- 2014.1.318.545) to my application

Application is in MVC5 ,

Then in Web.Config

i added a

EX:- web.config

```
<namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
        <add namespace="Kendo.Mvc.UI" />
</namespaces>
```

But When I try To use kendo ui widget on cshtml page i get error :- the type or namespace name kendo not found , are you missing a assembly?

i have to try this too , @using Kendo.Mvc.UI

but still i get same issue ?

Please suggest how to solve it.
regards,
vinit

Comment: refer this https://onabai.wordpress.com/2013/07/17/kendoui-multiselect-in-a-grid-part-2-yes-we-can/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you followed [this](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/asp-net-mvc-5) guide?  Also, did you add the **Kendo.Mvc.UI** namespace to the **Views/Web.config**?  You do not need to add that namespace to the project Web.config.

Comment: Hi I have Followed that guide and do same as in Guidline and i add Kendo.Mvc.UI namespace to the Views/Web.config , but still i get red underline in Kendo.Mvc.UI on View page and Threr is messag that namespace or accembly missing , but 1 thing i notice that if i build application and run it, it will work, but i want inteligency (put function name and ctrl + space and i got all method name with tooltip that is not working), can you suggest me any new idea.

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem even though followed official document, quick fixed by add below on my view.

```
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI
```